# Data type conversion error in derived column

Tags: ssis

Why it is not converting the data type of the column, the initial datatype of the column is DT_STR

(DT_I8)(ISNULL(Column_Name) ? (DT_I8)NULL(DT_I8) : (DT_I8)Column_Name)

But still I am getting DT_STR as an ouput parameter

Comment: What is the format of Column_Name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it seems redundant converting to a DT_STR even though you know it's already a DT_STR but SSRS can be finicky:

```
(DT_I8)(ISNULL((DT_STR,5,1252)Column_Name) ? (DT_I8)NULL(DT_I8) : (DT_I8)(DT_STR,5,1252)Column_Name)
```

I did this in a **derived column** with both your way and my way coming from a DT_STR field that stored numbers and managed to get an eight-byte signed integer.

Hope this helps!